# MySQL DATE_ADD - date is wrong?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

So I've got a simple query in MySQL that sets a new member's expiration date once they pay their dues:

```
UPDATE members SET joined=CURDATE(), expires=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR), active='1' WHERE id=1000
```

this query has run 200+ times, normally with the correct result - the current date is put in the joined field, and a year from that date in the expires field.  However, in about 10 instances, the expires date has been set to 00-00-0000 with no obvious explanation. I started writing the query to a text file every time to make sure the syntax was correct and I hadn't missed anything - and I didn't - it's exactly that query (with only the ID varying) for every query, those that work, and those that don't.

The only thing I can think here is that there must be an issue with MySQL's DATE_ADD function.  Has anyone else experienced anything like this?

UPDATE:
I should add that the joined field is correct with the current date in the cases where the expires date is incorrect.

- I'm using MySQL 5.0.81.
- There are no triggers.
- The table is using MyISAM.

IMPORTANT UPDATE:
I'm an idiot - when I say 11-30-1999 that's not actually what's in the database.  I absent-mindedly wrote that, but in fact the database contains the value 00-00-0000 - 11-30-1999 is just how it gets rendered by PHP onto my page.  Sorry about that, hopefully that will make this problem less difficult to figure out.

Comment: Could you please post the values of `joined` for the incorrect rows?

Comment: Yes - the latest two happened at the same time.  joined actually only stores the date (both are '8-4-05') but the row is created right before this query is run, and it is timestamped - '2009-08-04 22:38:20'. The other one is a few seconds after this.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought.... those "wrong" dates didn't happen to be leap year dates did they.... Feb. 29th for example?

It shouldn't matter, but it may be a bug.

Comment: No, the new records that have been created have a current date of now (July/August 2009) and expire in 2010.